# JFileChooser hangs the application

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am developing a java application and i am trying to make use if the JFileChooser. When i tried to test it alone and put those three lines

```
JFileChooser jf2 = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = jf2.showSaveDialog(this);

String saveTo = jf2.getSelectedFile().getPath();
```

It works perfectly but when i put it in a function in my application. the File Chooser doesn't show up and the whole frame hangs(doesn't respond

Please ask if more information is need or anything is unclear
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean with putting it in a function? how exactly do you put it in a function?

Comment: i made a function like this

void show my dialogDialog(){

}
and inside it put :
JFileChooser jf2 = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = jf2.showSaveDialog(this);

String saveTo = jf2.getSelectedFile().getPath(); 

and made a button that calls this function

Comment: This needs more code. Can you provide at least a full method?

Comment: this doesn't help. please show the complete implmentation that is not working, not only the one that works.

Comment: It's a 4000 lines chat application. so i don't want to dump all the code in here and make it a nightmare

Comment: If it's commented + styled correctly it wont be a nightmare to post maybe 30 to 50 lines of code. Just cut and paste in what's relevant, such as where you're calling the method, exactly how the method is written, etc